# How to get all the rows present in a dataset?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

For example if I have the below code that should bring all the values in the combo-box1 from all the values present in a sql database:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(dset.Tables(0).Rows().Item("P_ID").ToString())
```

SO how should i make sure that I get all values regardless of any specific row??
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to loop thru all the rows in dset and add each one?

Comment: @Plutonix - NO i have'nt tried any loops

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to code any looping if you want to populate a combobox with ALL the values coming from a specific table.

Edit: You can create a new dataset with the filtered data. Such as:

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString)

Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE YOUR_CONDITION"
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)
Dim ds As New DataSet
da.Fill(ds)

With ComboBox1
    .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    .DisplayMember = "P_ID"
    .ValueMember = "P_ID"
    .SelectedIndex = 0
End With
```

Comment: but sir, i have a sql command (not shown here) that filters values based on a certain criterion.

Comment: @fluuufffy Do you filter the table directly using that sql command? See my edits above